# Nested filtering of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two arrays:

`countriesArr`:

```
  [
      {
        "countryCode": "DEU",
        "name": "Germany",
        "companyFunctions": [
          {
            "name": "E-Commerce",
            "companyName": "Company 1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "countryCode": "FRA",
        "name": "France",
        "companyFunctions": [
          {
            "name": "Shopping Centre",
            "companyName": "Company 1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Support Services",
            "companyName": "Company 2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Procurement Support",
            "companyName": "Company 3"
          },
          {
            "name": "Retail",
            "companyName": "Company 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

and `filterArr`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Company 2", 
        "id": "32434d324-32434"
    },
    {
        "name": "Company 3", 
        "id": "2643d3254-39244"
    }
]
```

What I want to do is filter the `countriesArr` by looping through the `countriesArr` array where `countriesArr.companyFunctions.companyName === filterArr.name`.

I wrote the following code:

```
countriesArr.filter(p =>
    p.companyFunctions.filter(cF =>
        filterArr.filter(c => c.name === cF.companyName)
    )
);
```

But this doesn't seem to work as it returns also the German object from `countriesArr` and it includes `Company 1` in the `companyFunctions` of the French object from `countriesArr` while `Company 1` isn't in the `filterArr`.

What am I doing wrong?

The desired result should look like:

```
[
  {
    "countryCode": "FRA",
    "name": "France",
    "companyFunctions": [
      {
        "name": "Support Services",
        "companyName": "Company 2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Procurement Support",
        "companyName": "Company 3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Retail",
        "companyName": "Company 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: `.filter()` always returns an array. And every array (empty or not) is always [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated the question with the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rebuild a new object if `companyFunctions` contains the wanted names.

This approach take a hash table for wanted `names` where the property is `true`. This allows to filter later just with the [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) property `companyName`  and a simple call of the property of `names`.

Finally, if the filteres array has a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (any other value except zero) length, take this array along with the rest of the object and pus a new object to the result set.

```js
const
    countriesArr = [{ countryCode: "DEU", name: "Germany", companyFunctions: [{ name: "E-Commerce", companyName: "Company 1" }] }, { countryCode: "FRA", name: "France", companyFunctions: [{ name: "Shopping Centre", companyName: "Company 1" }, { name: "Support Services", companyName: "Company 2" }, { name: "Procurement Support", companyName: "Company 3" }, { name: "Retail", companyName: "Company 3" }] }],
    filterArr = [{ name: "Company 2", id: "32434d324-32434" }, { name: "Company 3", id: "2643d3254-39244" }],
    names = filterArr.reduce((r, { name }) => (r[name] = true, r), {}),
    result = countriesArr.reduce((r, { companyFunctions, ...o }) => {
        companyFunctions = companyFunctions.filter(({ companyName }) => names[companyName]);
        if (companyFunctions.length) r.push({ ...o, companyFunctions });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I would like to accept your answer could you briefly explain what is happening? It's very daunting to read.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const countriesArr = [
    {
        countryCode: 'DEU',
        name: 'Germany',
        companyFunctions: [
            {
                name: 'E-Commerce',
                companyName: 'Company 1',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        countryCode: 'FRA',
        name: 'France',
        companyFunctions: [
            {
                name: 'Shopping Centre',
                companyName: 'Company 1',
            },
            {
                name: 'Support Services',
                companyName: 'Company 2',
            },
            {
                name: 'Procurement Support',
                companyName: 'Company 3',
            },
            {
                name: 'Retail',
                companyName: 'Company 3',
            },
        ],
    },
];

const filterArr = [
    {
        name: 'Company 2',
        id: '32434d324-32434',
    },
    {
        name: 'Company 3',
        id: '2643d3254-39244',
    },
].map((f) => f.name);

const result = countriesArr
    .map((c) => ({
        ...c,
        companyFunctions: c.companyFunctions.filter((cf) => filterArr.includes(cf.companyName)),
    }))
    .filter((c) => c.companyFunctions.length > 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not a filter over `countriesArr` but a *map()* (to **transform** it) and then a *filter()* (to remove entries with 0 companyFunctions) or vice-versa (first *filter()* those having at least one matching `companyFunction` and then map to transform removing unwanted ones). But mapping and then filtering seems more straightforward to me...

```
const result = countriesArr                                                 
    .map(function(ca) {                                                     
        ca.companyFunctions = ca.companyFunctions.filter(                   
                cf => filterArr.some(fa=>fa.name==cf.companyName)           
        );                                                                  
        return ca;                                                          
    })                                                                      
    .filter(ca=>ca.companyFunctions.length)                                 
;                                                                           
                                                                            
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));                               
// [                                                                        
//     {                                                                    
//         "countryCode": "FRA",                                            
//         "name": "France",                                                
//         "companyFunctions": [                                            
//             {                                                            
//                 "name": "Support Services",                              
//                 "companyName": "Company 2"                               
//             },                                                           
//             {                                                            
//                 "name": "Procurement Support",                           
//                 "companyName": "Company 3"                               
//             },                                                           
//             {                                                            
//                 "name": "Retail",                                        
//                 "companyName": "Company 3"                               
//             }                                                            
//         ]                                                                
//     }                                                                    
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var countriesArr = [{
    "countryCode": "DEU",
    "name": "Germany",
    "companyFunctions": [{
      "name": "E-Commerce",
      "companyName": "Company 1"
    }]
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "FRA",
    "name": "France",
    "companyFunctions": [{
        "name": "Shopping Centre",
        "companyName": "Company 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Support Services",
        "companyName": "Company 2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Procurement Support",
        "companyName": "Company 3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Retail",
        "companyName": "Company 3"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var filterArr = [{
    "name": "Company 2",
    "id": "32434d324-32434"
  },
  {
    "name": "Company 3",
    "id": "2643d3254-39244"
  }
]

console.log(countriesArr.filter(item => {
  return filterArr.findIndex(company => item.companyFunctions.some(d => d.companyName === company.name)) != -1
}))
```